# How to do multiple validations for a single value in yup?

Tags: reactjs, formik, yup

Using joi on the server side, I can do multiple validations like
`id: [joi.string().email(), joi.string().min(10)]`.

How can we do this on frontend using formik and yup? I went through the docs and still no success.

Comment: What I want to do is validate email or phone number both in a single field i.e id.

Answer (score 3):

You should try Yup like this.

```
const formikEnhancer = withFormik({
      validationSchema: Yup.object().shape({
        name: Yup.string().strict(true).lowercase('Name must be lowercase').matches(/^\S+$/, 'Name must not contain spaces').matches(/^(?:(?!\.).)*$\r?\n?/, 'Name must not contain period').max(10, 'Maximum of 10 characters')
          .required('Name is required!'),
         email: Yup.string().strict(true).lowercase('Email must be lowercase').required('Email is required!')
      })
    })
```

Comment: I am using formik like that only. My concern is how to do two different validations on a single field. If it passes any of the validation, let it submit.

Comment: you can use .test('testName','message',function(value){
 return yup.number().min(5).isValid(value) || ...other tests 
 })